# Can I send User as object to FluentEmail in .To() EmailService

Tags: c#, email, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to pass User object in `Fleunt EmailService()` such as

```
var email = await Email
                .From("helpdesk@gmail.com")
                .To(UserObject)
                .Subject("Test Email")
                .Body(body: discussion.Content)
                .SendAsync();
```

Since I have a bunch of user and `.To()` needs the contain User object, not hardcoded string.
I have around 10 users registered and Admin user, once User create post and when Admin answer on his/her post User should get notification via Email that Admin answer on his post.
I try to find some solution but unsuccessfully.
Anyone how can tell me does `FluentEmail` contain this options ?

Reference

[Reference](https://lukelowrey.com/send-email-in-dotnet-core-with-fluent-email/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a place where the fluent notation isn't strong.
I would make the code as follows:

```
var emailTemplate = Email.From("helpdesk@gmail.com")
                            .Subject("Test Email")
                            .Body(body: discussion.Content);
foreach(var to in toEmails)
{
    emailTemplate.To(to);
}           
var email = await emailTemplate.SendAsync();
```

Comment: This will indicate like that will send email address to every users register in system, not excplicitly User which I want to be sent. Like if communication start between `Admin` and `User` only User which create post should get notification

Comment: Sorry i assumed you wil have a list of email addresses that needed to receive the mail : toEmails

Comment: The scenario is little bit complicated and It is hard to explain. So I have `Admin` and `User`. Once `User` create post it it automatically store in `db`. And when Admin answer on his post, User should get notification that Admin answer on post. Thats why I am asking is there any solution for this or not. SInce I have never before user `FluentEmail`